# Flutter Web: Missing main.dart.js and JavaScript files when building with flutter build web, but working fine with flutter run

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-webui

I am running into an issue with Flutter web in which no JavaScript files are generated when running `flutter build web` in any project, causing prjects to simply load a blank page.

I am currently on version 1.18.0 beta channel, and this happens with every project, even with the default counter project that Flutter generates with `flutter create .`. No warnings or errors are thrown, and if I run the web project with `flutter run --release -d chrome`, everything works as intended.

I have followed the steps described in the [Building a web application with Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) article from the documentation, and I remember I was able to build and host a web project with Flutter half a year ago with no issues, following the same steps.

My Flutter configuration and SDKs seem to be in place. This is what I get if I run `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.18.0-11.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.18363.836], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.18.0-11.1.pre at D:\Programas\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 2738a1148b (4 weeks ago), 2020-05-13 15:24:36 -0700
    • Engine revision ef9215ceb2
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-8.2.beta)


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: D:\Programas\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at D:\Programas\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61
```

What might be wrong here? Why are no JavaScripts files being generated?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please check the following folder:

`./your-app/build/web`

I had the same problem and was checking the wrong folder (`./your-app/web`).

Comment: True! In the end I figured that out and forgot about this question, so I did not update it, but indeed I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting same error when running from `myapp/build/web/index.html`. It has `main.dart.js` file but still reports the error. It seems it is looking for the fine in directly in the root directory `file:///D:/main.dart.js` instead of the same web folder.

Answer (score 9):

1. make sure to copy files, from:
   `./your-app/build/web`
2. If the error still exists, update the index.html
   Example: 
   a. my flutter project at web server: `webserver/flutter_project/index.html` 
   b. open the index.html
   c. update `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/flutter_project/">`

Comment: You can also update `<base href="/">` in web/index.html instead of in build/web/index.html, so that the *source* index.html file contains the correct base path. This works with `flutter run` and `flutter build web`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the `flutter.js` file is not generated when building for web.
What I do is run `flutter clean` then run `flutter build web` again.
You should see the missing js file and make sure to check on `build/web` not `web` on the root.

Comment: I have the same issue and don't know the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

For those who cant open builded version:
Go to 'app/build/web' and run a server from there `python -m http.server 8000`, or by using the dhttpd package

[Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that worked for me is updating to
`<base href="./">` from `<base href="/">`. So current path instead of root

Answer (score 0):

In my case (IIS) .json files are available in my directory but are not published by the web server. I had to add MIME types to allow them. Same question for .otf files.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that .gitignore had `*.dart.js`, which didn't allow main.dart.js file to upload to the repository.

As I have my deployment path as /dist/web, I added the following exception:

`!/dist/**`

So every file from that path uploads.